# Cálculo para determinar se triângulo é retângulo não dá resultado esperado

Tags: c, matemática, lógica

O programa que criei recebe três valores inteiros, calcula dentro do `if` esses valores e caso a condição for correta ele deveria mostrar na tela o SIM (o triangulo é retângulo), e caso a condição não seja satisfeita, deve mostrar NAO.

Digitando os valores 3, 4 e 5 a saída tem de ser SIM, digitando 3, 3 e 4, a saída deveria ser NAO, mas esta dando SIM em todos os casos.

Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)

{
    int hip, cat1, cat2;

    scanf("%d", &cat1);

    scanf("%d", &cat2);

    scanf("%d", &hip);

    if (hip = pow(cat1,2) + pow(cat2,2))
    {
        printf("SIM");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("NAO");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Como resolver?

Comment: use == no lugar de =, e também pra ser a formula do triangulo retangulo deve ter raiz.

Comment: Liga os warnings do teu compilador e corrige-os todos antes de aceitar o executavel.

Comment: Se suas entradas são inteiras, uma solução mais simples como as da resposta do bigown trará resultados corretos sempre. Apenas quando se admite entradas em ponto flutuante (o que extrapola a pergunta, mas estou citando por completeza) é que uma solução aproximada se faz necessária - caso em que a resposta do JJoao demonstra o modo mais usual de tratar do problema (estabelecer uma margem de erro para as comparações em PF). Aqui está [um exemplo](http://ideone.com/3NefCR) que ajuda a comprovar a correção dos métodos apresentados.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Há dois problemas:

1. Você usou `=` e não `==`, para comparar é o segundo, você atribuiu uma novo valor para a hipotenusa.
2. Você não usou a raiz quadrada, portanto a fórmula está errada. Mas existe uma fórmula melhor.

Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void) {
    int hip, cat1, cat2;
    scanf("%d", &cat1);
    scanf("%d", &cat2);
    scanf("%d", &hip);
    if (hip * hip == cat1 * cat1 + cat2 * cat2) printf("SIM");
    else printf("NAO");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/HJEOJI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/detjxojp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/Power.c). Note que eu fiz um pouco diferente lá.

Comment: Sugestao: em vez de calcular a raiz quadrada (duas vezes), compara os quadrados: `if (hip*hip == cat1*cat1 + cat2*cat2)`

Comment: a solução do @pmg está correta. A pergunta é somente para inteiros. Exatamente como em http://ideone.com/E3Cxp0. Para valores quebrados utiliza-se a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 4):

Variante da versão anterior (@Maniero)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ERROMAX 0.0001

int main (void) {
    float hip, cat1, cat2;
    scanf("%f", &cat1);
    scanf("%f", &cat2);
    scanf("%f", &hip);
    if (fabsf(hip - sqrt(pow(cat1,2) + pow(cat2,2))) < ERROMAX ) {
        printf("SIM\n");
    } else {
        printf("NAO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

de modo a dar

```
1 1 1 -> não 

3 4 5 -> sim
```

Comment: `abs` é só para inteiros (e existe no `stdlib.h`, não no `math.h`), acho que você quis dizer `fabs`, certo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, tens todissima a razão! vou corrigir imediatamente! (eu estava a pensar fabsf (para floats) mas o fabs (para doubles também dá).