# Problema com programa de equação do segundo grau

Tags: c

Estou com um problema interessante no meu código, o programa lê três números e diz se é um triangulo retângulo ou não, mas o problema é que dependendo da sequencia que eu digito os números, o programa da erro, pois o maior valor digitado deve ser o da hipotenusa e tanto faz os outros dois catetos, caso eu digite 3, 4, 5, o valor de 5 precisa ser armazenado na variável hipotenusa, mas como faço isso, 5, 4, 3 da certo mas o contrario não...

```
#include <stdio.h> //Inclusao da bibilioteca principal
#include <math.h> //Inclusao da biblioteca para uso da funcao "pow" e "sqrt"

int main (void) //Declaracao do corpo principal do programa

{
    int hip, cat1, cat2; //Declaracao de variaveis hipoteusa, cateto 1 e cateto 2

    scanf("%d", &hip); //Insercao pdo valor da hipotenusa
    scanf("%d", &cat1); //Insercao do valor do cateto 1
    scanf("%d", &cat2); //Insercao do valor do cateto 2

    if (hip == sqrt(pow(cat1,2) + pow(cat2,2))) //Condicao para caso o valor da hipotenusa seja igual a raiz quadrada da soma dos quadrados dos catetos
    {
        printf("SIM"); //Caso a condicao acima seja verdade, imprimi na tela a palavra SIM
    } else {
        printf("NAO"); //Caso a condicao acima nao for satisfeita, imprimi na tela a palavra NAO
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A hipotenusa sempre é o lado maior do triangulo. Você pode ler lado1, lado2, lado3, em qualquer ordem. Depois você faz uma função para descobrir qual o lado maior. E só então você aplica a sua formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na lógica. Você assumiu que o usuário irá inserir primeiro a hipotenusa, e em seguida os catetos. Deve se fazer a verificação de qual o maior número inserido e armazená-lo na variável hip. Eis um exemplo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(){
    int hip, cat1, cat2, n1, n2, n3;
    scanf("%i", &n1);
    scanf("%i", &n2);
    scanf("%i", &n3);
    // Verifica se a hipotenusa é o n1
    if(n1>n2 && n1>n3) {
        hip = n1;
        cat1 = n2;
        cat2 = n3;
    } else if(n2>n1 && n2>n3) { //Verifica se a hipotenusa é n2
        hip = n2;
        cat1 = n1;
        cat2 = n3;
    } else {
        hip = n3;
        cat1 = n1;
        cat2 = n2;  
    }
    if(hip == (pow(cat1, 2) + pow(cat2, 2))) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    } else {
        printf("No\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Testei aqui funcionou.
Veja se é esse seu objetivo.
At.,
Samuel Gomes

Answer (score 2):

Segue uma alternativa ao código do @SamuelGomes, com o problema de arredondamento solucionado com a retirada do `sqrt`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)

{
    int n1, n2, n3, t;

    scanf("%d", &n1);
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    scanf("%d", &n3);

    if ( n2 > n1 ) {
        t  = n1;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = t;
    }

    if ( n3 > n1 ) {
        t  = n1;
        n1 = n3;
        n3 = t;
    }

    if ( n1 * n1 == n2 * n2 + n3 * n3 )
    {
        printf("SIM");
    } else {
        printf("NAO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As respostas à pergunta anterior tratam do problema de arredondamento:
[Cálculo para determinar se triângulo é retângulo não dá resultado esperado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56916)