# Problema em verificação de triangulo em C

Tags: c

O programa visa identificar se um triangulo é equilátero, isósceles ou escaleno. 
Mas ocorre um erro na linha de identificação do isósceles, onde se o usuário colocar valores de entradas iguais nos dois primeiros lados e diferente no ultimo, ele não é reconhecido.

Exemplo:

- medida do lado1: `3`;
- medida do lado2: `4`;
- medida do lado3: `2`;

---

Código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int L1,L2,L3;
    int equilatero,isoceles,escaleno;


    printf("media do lado1:");
    scanf("%d",&L1);

    printf("media do lado2:");
    scanf("%d",&L2);

    printf("media do lado3:");
    scanf("%d",&L3);

    equilatero = (L1 == L2)&&(L1 == L3);
    printf("seu triangulo eh equilatero: %d\n",equilatero);

    isoceles = ((L1==L2)||(L1==L3)||(L2==L3))&&((L1!=L2)||(L2=!L3)||(L1=!L3));
    printf("seu triangulo eh isoceles: %d \n",isoceles);

    escaleno = (L1 != L2)&&(L2 != L3)&&(L1 != L3);
    printf("seu triangulo eh escaleno: %d \n",escaleno);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Veja se te ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56916/101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O sua verificação do isósceles esta errada, por isso não da certo,
o correto seria:

```
isoceles = (((L1 == L2) && (L2 != L3)) || ((L2 == L3) && (L3 != L1)) || ((L3 == L1) && (L3 != L2)));
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou, não entendi muito bem o motivo da minha verificação estar errada, mas a sua linha funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Na verdade o seu pensamento esta corretíssimo, porém, você escreveu seu pensamento de forma errada. Nas duas ultimas verificações, ao invés de colocar != você colocou =!, e por isso não deu certo.